# When do global sections of a $\mathcal{O}_X$-Module $\mathcal{F}$ that generate $\mathcal{F}_x$ also generate $\mathcal{F}$ in a neighborhood of $x$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $\newcommand{\m}{\mathcal}(X, \m{O}_X)$ be a ringed space, $\m{F}$ a $\m{O}_X$-Module and $x \in X$ a point. Now let $s_1, \dots, s_n \in \Gamma(X, \m{F})$ be such that $s_{1, x}, \dots, s_{n, x}$ generate $\m{F}_x$.

Under which conditions (e. g. $X$ (locally Noetherian) Scheme, $\m{F}$ (quasi-)Coherent) doest the above imply that there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $s_1|_U, \dots, s_n|_U$ generate $\m{F}|_U$ ?

Comment: @user45765 So you suggest the conditions that $X$ be a scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ quasi-coherent?

Comment: @user45765 wouldn't you also need the module in the local setting to be finitely generated, i.e. $\mathcal{F} \in \mathrm{Coh}(X)$? Else I don't see how you get around the problem of having to invert infinitely many denominators.

Comment: What is the word for "there is an open cover $X=\cup_j U_j$ such that for all set $V \subset U_j$ then $\mathcal{F}(V) = O_X(V) \mathcal{F}(U_j)$" ? And that the $ \mathcal{F}(U_j)$ are finitely generated ? Then the inverse of the linear relations between its generators and the $s_n$ is in $O_X(W\cap U)$ and the $s_n$ generate $\mathcal{F}(W\cap U_j)$.

Comment: @user45765 Mumford however requires $\mathcal{F}$ to be locally finitely generated. (That's what I was worried about in my previous comment, but of course requiring Noetherian when you only need finitely generated is overkill.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the book [Algebraic Geomtry 1 by Görtz, Wedhorn](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-8348-9722-0) you'll find the following proposition on page $191$

> Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ be a ringed space and let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite type. Let $x \in  X$ be a point and let $s_i  \in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})$ for $i =1,\dots,n$ be sections over some open neighborhood of $x$ such that the germs $(s_i)_x$ generate the stalk $\mathcal{F}_x$. Then there exists an open neighborhood $V \subseteq U$, such that the $s_i|_V$ generate $\mathcal{F}|_V$.

You also have this proposition on page $196$

> Let $X$ be a locally noetherian scheme and let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module. Then the following assertions are equivalent:
>
> - $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent
> - $\mathcal{F}$ is of finite presentation
> - $\mathcal{F}$ is of finite type and quasi-coherent.

On page $190$ they write  if $X$ is a locally noetherian scheme, an $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module is of finite type if and only if it is of finite presentation. So you might think that we don't need the extra condition in the above proposition. But this statement is false. As mentioned in the [errata](https://www.algebraic-geometry.de/errata/)

> In general, there are $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules of finite type that are not of finite presentation even over Noetherian schemes: take a quotient of $\mathcal{O}_X$ by a non-quasi coherent sheaf of ideals. It is true that a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module of finite type over a Noetherian scheme is of finite presentation.